# Scaling website content until first breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to do next behavior on my webssite: until first breakpoint (for tablets) it should just scale without changing of elements positions etc. For example: Website should look similar on 1920x1280 screen and on 1600x900 screen, but on tablets and mobiles i want to use media queries for reform my elements position.

So question is how to allow my website to scale on laptop \ PC screens with different sizes until first breakpoint is reached.

Comment: It is not clear what is required because you have not discussed what is to happen on different viewport aspect ratios. You might also think about coding right from the start not in absolute units like pixels but in terms of the vw unit for example. Please think this through and show us an example of what you have already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your answer at the post of "WizardOfOz" correctly, you just want to "scale the whole page" at breakpoint "1600x900"? Then you can use:

```
@media(max-width:1600px){
  html {
    transform: scale(0.9); // you can change the "(0.9)" to what you need
  }
}
```

**BUT:** this is not a common way. The correct way would be to redefine the elements themselves, also the fonts, like this way:

```
.MyDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


@media(max-width:1600px){
.MyDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just wrap all your elements in a container width a max width of 1600px? That should keep all child elements intact as the window width grows. Then have it responsive from 1600px and below?

```
.container{
  max-width:1600px; // or whatever your largest size
  height: auto;
}

@media(max-width:1600px){
  // Your css for screens smaller than 1600px
}

<section class ="container">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I need to scale everything. Not just child views width. I mean font sizes, heights of child views etc.

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to do that automatically, I think you might need to scale all those manually under the media query.